# Trim to first number

Tags: c#, trim

Is there a way to trim a string to the first numeric digit from left AND right using standard .NET tools? Or I need to write my own function (not difficult, but I'd rather use standard methods). I need the following outputs for the provided inputs:

```
Input           Output
-----------------------
abc123def       123
;'-2s;35(r      2s;35
abc12de3f4g     12de3f4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

```
string TrimToDigits(string text)
{
    var pattern = @"\d.*\d";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);

    Match m = regex.Match(text);   // m is the first match
    if (m.Success)
    {
        return m.Value;
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

If you want to call this like you normally would the `String.Trim()` method, you can create it as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    static string TrimToDigits(this string text)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
var trimmedString = otherString.TrimToDigits();
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution (although not the standard Trim function). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built in way. You will have to write your own method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is. Method though:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(str[i]))
    {
        break;
    }
    str = string.Substring(1);
}
for (int i = str.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(str[i]))
    {
        break;
    }
    str = string.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
}
```

I think this'll work.